# SQL Server is not using my index. How to having it using my index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

My client is using a table to create financial reports per month. I have optimized it as there were around 40 aggregations columns and it was running for around 40 minutes to see the output. I created a process that stores the values for the aggregations into a tables and now, when selecting the columns, the aggregations are already calculated and it runs in 3-4 minutes.
Now I'm trying to create an index but due to the big volume of data (I guess) SQL Server is not using it.
The query is pretty simple

```sql
Select * 
From Table
Where year(data_doc) = 2023
and month(data_doc) = 10
```

I created a non-clustered index only for the column 'data_doc' but the SQL server still scanned the whole table. I altered the index an included the columns that make the primary key like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Data_Doc ON Tabel(data_doc,OperationDetail_Id, OperationTraceOut_Id,OperationTraceIn_Id).
```

It's important to say that the client is using a view and the 'select * from view' returns around 57 millions rows and that there are 57 columns in total. Using the filter per year and month, it returns around 2/3 millions of rows. The column 'data_doc' datatype is 'datetime'.

How can I create the indexes to optimize the process?

Comment: What you describe is a data warehouse. Data warehouses always have a Calendar table or Date dimension to handle these problems.

Answer (score 5):

Your `WHERE` is not SARGable (it doesn't contain **s**earchable **arg**uments), so the index is "useless" for that query as it can't be used. You need to use date ranges, not functions on your columns in the `WHERE`.

```sql
SELECT <Explicit List of Columns you need>
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE Data_doc >= '20231001'
  AND Data_doc < '20231101';
```

Also, however, your `SELECT` had `SELECT *` and I doubt that the table only has those 3 columns in it. As a result even *if* the query is SARGable, it may result in a scan if the data engine estimates the cost of doing (many) key lookups is more expensive than a scan. If that's the case, you'll likely need to change your index to `INCLUDE` the other columns in the table, or better only return the columns from the table you need (as I suggest in the code) and ensure *at least* those (other) columns are in the `INCLUDE`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are applying a function to the date column, SQL Server can't use the index. Instead, you can rewrite the query, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE date >= '2023-10-01' AND date < '2023-11-01'
```

Or like this with a date parameter:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2023-10-01'

SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE date >= @date AND date < DATEADD(month, 1, @date)
```

Answer (score 3):

The *query* prevents the server from using the index. This isn't a SQL Server problem. Indexes, in all databases, are built using the actual field values. When the query uses `Where year(date) = 2023 and month(date) = 10` it's trying to filter using calculated values that aren't stored in any index.

The best way to handle this is to use a [Calendar or Dimension table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), a table with precalculated dates for eg 10-20 years and additional indexed columns for Year, Month, Day, WeekDay, Week Number, Semester, Quarter, etc or whatever reporting period you want. This is common in all data warehouse designs.

Using a Calendar table you can filter or group by any period you want easily. It's also possible to perform period-over-period calculations using windowing functions like `LEAD`, `LAG`, `SUM() OVER()` etc.

Your particular query would become eg:

```
Select * 
From Sales s INNER JOIN Calendar c on s.Date=c.Date
Where c.Year = 2023
and c.Month = 10
```

Extra columns per reporting period can be used for filtering, grouping and labeling :

```
Select Category,YearMonth,sum(Amount) 
From Sales s INNER JOIN Calendar c on s.Date=c.Date
Where c.YearMonth IN ('2023M10','2022M10')
GROUP BY Category,YearMonth
```

A calendar table isn't very large, which means it's easy to index all the columns you need. It's also a great candidate for compression and columnstore indexing.

---

> 40 aggregations columns
>
> 57 millions rows and that there are 57 columns

That's a roundabout way of describing a Fact table in a Data Warehouse. It's quite possible there's a Date dimension already. Even if it isn't, a Calendar table with a Columnstore index can speed up querying significantly, especially if the fact table is also a Columnstore

Answer (score -1):

A [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) can be *persisted* and *indexed*. You could add an indexed computed column that contains the year/month in sorting order, i.e. `YYYYMM`, using the expression `Year( data_doc ) * 100 + Month( data_doc )`.

Indexing the computed column would let you perform a query using the index, e.g. `... where YearMonth = 202310;` or `... where 202301 <= YearMonth and YearMonth <= 202312;`, that could benefit from the index.